# Who's linking to my MS Access tables?

Tags: vba, ms-access

We've got a MS Database (.mdb file) that is heavily accessed by many people on the network. However, this file is going to be moved soon and we don't know who we need to inform before the move occurs.

Is there anyway to start keeping a log of everyone who accesses this database indirectly?

We've got a VBA script that fires when the database is opened directly to record important information so we can contact them but we've found majority of the users don't actually open the database, instead they are using local databases of their own that are LINKED to the main database.

Most databases are either 2007/2010 using the .acccdb extension. Only this "main database" is using the old .mdb extension.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database is accessed using the database primitives provided by the file system and it's network re-director. So the file system and the network re-director always know who is accessing the file (and, actually, who is accessing the physical records inside the file).

An easy way to to log this is to use the Security Log in the Windows Event Log system on the File Server. To do this, select the database file, right click, and select "properties", “Security”, "Advanced" then the Auditing tab. Add "everyone" to the audit list. I would add "anonymous" as well, but if you get any "anonymous" access, you've got bigger problems.

You also need to enable audit logging of "objects", through group policy (on a domain system) or local policy (on a file server in system/network/workgroup without group policy). The one you want is Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy > Audit Object Access

The log that you need to enable, that will get this information, is the log on server where the database file is stored. It's logging access at the file end (which is one place) not at the request end (which could be anywhere).

edit>
To query and export from the log, you can use "eventquery.vbs", if you've got a copy on one of your servers. It uses execquery on a WMI object. If you haven't got eventquery.vbs, you may want to look for a PowerShell alternative.

Comment: This is awesome! I've got it working but how can I access the Event Logs more conveniently? At the moment I have to open each record and see who's accessed the database. I've got a XML query to create a custom view only to show the event entries relevant to this particular database but is there a way to view them more conveniently than to open each one individually? I tried exporting the view to PDF/CSV but it only exports a summary - the information I need is in the "Detailed View"..