# View Back end Connections to Access DB from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I Have a database that many people across my workplace have excel files with linked tables etc.

There are times where it is critical I have exclusive access to the DB and it is not feasible to track down hundreds of possible excel files with links that do not properly break and revamp them; especially when people are makign new files all the time.

I found the following code that allows me to see whether someone is connected o the front end of the database:

```
Sub ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i, j As Long

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
' in the Jet 4.0 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, _
, "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

'Output the list of all users in the current database.

Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, "", rs.Fields(1).Name, _
"", rs.Fields(2).Name, rs.Fields(3).Name

While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), _
    rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

is there any code that will do the same thing as this to give me back end connections? As in who has an open excel file that is linked and locking the DB to Read- Only?

Comment: Not Access VBA but found this using the security log. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442037/whos-linking-to-my-ms-access-tables/19442487

Answer (score 0):

1) You can open a connection to any database. You've used "CurrentProject.Connection", but you can use:

```
set cn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"
```

2) If method (1) is not suitable, you can use ODBC to query WMI and get a list of everyone connected to any particular file.

Comment: 1) is the method i use in my excel files; when someone is in the DB using that connection, it prevents another user from accessing it.

could you elaborate on the method for 2)?

Comment: ^ see above comment @david